# Host files in S3, allow public read but not downloading

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, media

I would like to host a few media files on S3, and use a nice JS player to fetch the media, but I don't want general public to be able to download the files (they are commercial sounds and videos).

Is there a policy that one can set up (in meta-policy) like: "allow streaming from anyone, restrict downloading from all"?
Or am I confined to use Soundcloud?

Thanks

Comment: Files on SoundCloud are easily downloadable. If someone can listen to the audio, someone can figure out how to download it.

Comment: Well then (even though they have a "Allow Download" checkbox...), thanks for pointing that out. Do you have an answer to my question though?

Comment: The answer to your question is fundamentally "it's not possible". SoundCloud's checkbox just affects whether or not there's a "download" link/button along with the sound. Anyone with a little bit of technical knowledge can get at the file. This is true even for stuff like Netflix videos - a little technical knowhow and it's possible to rip it. The only way to reliably prevent someone from downloading a copyrighted asset is not to put it on the internet in the first place.

Comment: Alright, but keep in mind my question is specifically about S3, not Soundcloud per se.

Comment: And my statements are general. They are not specific to SoundCloud and apply to S3 as well. If a user's browser can play a sound, the user can download the sound, regardless of where/how it's hosted.

Answer (score 2):

Most network traffic from a browser will be accessible to anyone. Plugins allow for some more hiding of the files but are usually reverse-engineer-able enough to get the files out.

Flash is commonly used to hide this access and stream the media without exposing the media location inside the browser. The media can still be gotten using a proxy, which will expose the flash network traffic.

Best rule of thumb is to keep access to the data annoying enough that people won't want to get to it for what they wish to download. And commercial sounds and videos should be put up understanding that they could be leaked but to minimize the risk.